# java generics problem - create a generic list when the type is of yet unknown object type

Tags: java, generics

I want to open a configuration screen and send back its data when user clicks ok.

I have these objects as configurations

```
configObjA a;  
configObjB b;
```

Both implement IDisplayable (my interface).
Now the congfig screen gets two ArrayLists and put them in JLists gui.
it itterates the JList and put them in datamodel.

when I return from the screen , I want to send the main screen the results.
So I re-iterate the datamodel and put it all back in an arraylist

the problem is the main screen doesnt know anything about 
Is there a way my configuration screen would return a type that the main screen will know?

I thought of returning 
    public List getOptionsList() 
and in the method I wil create a list of the type I sent. (I would then have to keep the type i sent ). is that any good? how do i create a generic list when the type is of unknown
object type? any suggestion ?

btw: isnt my foolish gui process too complicated for that simple need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how do i create a generic list when the type is of unknown object type?

You cannot. The whole point of generic lists is that you do know the object type at compile-time, so that the compiler can check your usage of that list.

If you know at least a parent class or interface (which is the usual case actually), you can use that:

```
List<IDisplayable> l;
```

If it can be any type of object, you can only say

```
List<Object> l;
```

which will accept any kind of Object, but removes the potential for meaningful compile-time type checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic list of an unknown type, but you can't really put objects in them.

```
public <T> List<T> makeList() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Of course, the method using this method then has to know the type, and can only put objects of this type in.

---

In your case, the problem seems to be that you want to misuse the JList as a data container. It is not, it is a view component. Use a real data structure for your logic, and wrap it in a ListModel to provide your list with data to show.